# Passing query parameter to backend using at.js for twitter-style-mention triggered autocomplete

Tags: javascript, twitter, autocomplete, triggers

I'm using at.js via:

```
$('#post-body').atwho(
        at:"@",
        data: "/home/mention_autocomplete",
        limit: 7
        )
```

I would like to pass whatever the user has typed after the '@' symbol to the backend for query and returning relevant results. Is this data accessible inside the `.atwho()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `remote_filter` callback.

```
$('#inputor').atwho({
  at: '@', 
  callbacks: {
    remote_filter: function(query, callback) {
      $.getJSON("/home/mention_autocomplete", {q: 'whatever'}, function(data) {
        callback(data.usernames);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

ref: https://github.com/ichord/At.js/wiki